# Date.toString() gives a year different from the set one?

Tags: java, date

On Java 7 (Java 6 not tested):

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date test=new Date(2012, 12, 12);
        System.out.println("test=" + test.toString());
    }
}
```

gives me

```
test=Sun Jan 12 00:00:00 CET 3913
```

Note the year: 3913, which is different from the year (2012) I passed.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

(Yes, I know that the Date constructor I am using is deprecated.)

Comment: "Yes, I know that the Date constructor I am using is deprecated" - did you read the documentation for it though? When something doesn't behave as you expect, your first response should be to check the documentation. Ideally, move off deprecated APIs at the same time...

Comment: You should now probably clearly understand one of the reasons of deprecation.

Comment: Got 3 basically identically replies with same time they were posted, can't decide on real answer. Thanks to all! 10% my fault for not reading API, 90% others fault for bad API design ;-) BTW: On Calendar it's zero based month/day, "normal" year... WTF...

Comment: Day in `Calendar` is not zero based at all.

Answer (score 7):

That `Date` constructor takes the year minus 1900, [as specified in the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29).

(This is one of the many reasons you should use JODA whenever possible, which has a significantly better designed and less surprising API.  In particular, I'd rather remove my pinky finger with a rusty knife than use the built-in Java time API.)

Answer (score 3):

constructor for Java Date takes the year you would like and adds 1900 to it.  month is zero indexed too so

```
Date test=new Date(2012, 12, 12);
```

should become

```
Date test=new Date(2012-1900, 11, 12);
```

check out the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Date` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html):

> Parameters:
>
> year - the year minus 1900.
>
> month - the month between 0-11.

Obviously, `1900 + 2012 = 3912`. By going over the limit for the month value, you are essentially going past the specified year, hence the `3913` value.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `Date()` is defined as follows:

```
year - the year minus 1900; must be 0 to 8099. (Note that 8099 is 9999 minus 1900.)
```

This explains the discrepancy.